# How to find intersection of an arrays items on IronPython?

Tags: python, arrays, ironpython, intersection

I have an array like `a[[A,Apple,2],[A,Apple,4],[A,Orange,3],[A,Orange,2],[A,Pear,3],[B,Apple,4],[B,Orange,3],[B,Orange,2],[C,Apple,4],[C,Orange,3],[C,Orange,2]],[D,Berry,5],[D,Pear,3]`.I would like to find intersection of this items based on its index 0. For this example outcome should be `b[[Apple,4],[Orange,2],[Orange,3],[Pear,3]]`.

Its maybe a easy one but I am new to IronPython/Python. I couldn't make it work and I am trying for two days. Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: What are the rules of your intersection.  Specifically, how do you choose between elements which have the same item at index 0 but differ elsewhere . What will be the intersection of `[[A, Apple, 2], [A, Apple, 3], [A, Banana, 2], [A, Pear, 0]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Edited to a dict instead of a list. This will give you an dict with the keys `A,B,C` and so on.

```
a = [['A','Apple',2],['A','Apple',4],['A','Orange',3],['A','Orange',2],['A','Pear',3],['B','Apple',4],['B','Orange',3],['B','Orange',2],['B','Pear',3]]
b = {}
for i in a:
    if i[0] not in b.keys():
        b[i[0]] = [[i[1],i[2]]]
    else:
        b[i[0]].append([i[1],i[2]])
print(b) 
#{'A': [['Apple', 2], ['Apple', 4], ['Orange', 3], ['Orange', 2], ['Pear', 3]], 'B': [['Apple', 4], ['Orange', 3], ['Orange', 2], ['Pear', 3]]}
```

Comment: Hello Sefan thank you for your answer. You are correct if It was just A and B. But intersection could be between more than two

Comment: @MehmetSUBASI I have updated the code and it now creates a dict with the keys `A,B,C,...` and will now work for more than just A and B